# Create a function for each match in a textarea

Tags: jquery, function, foreach

I have a text area with some expressions in square brackets in it. I need to find all of the expressions inside the square brackets and add some code to each expression (wrap them inside )

So far I only managed to identify the expressions, but I can't find a way to run a loop function to deal with them (I was thinking of an "each" function)
example for html code:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <textarea>
      everyone [David] wants to travel the world [Paris] with a car [Fiat]
   </textarea>
</div>
```

my jQuery code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myText = $('#myDiv').text();
    var regex= /\[([^\]]*)\]/;
    var result = myText.match( /\[(.*)\]/  );
});
```

From here on every function I try just doesn't work... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to check your regex, if it is returning the correct match.  It is possible it is not returning the right match that you are expecting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {      
     var myText = $('#myDiv').text();
     var result = myText.replace(/\[/g, '<span>').replace(/\]/g, '</span>');
     $('#output').append(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
   <textarea>
      everyone [David] wants to travel the world [Paris] with a car [Fiat]
   </textarea>
   <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

The above code will match the text within [] and create a list and append it to a div with id output.  Cannot tell from the question if this is what you mean by `wrap them inside`.

Comment: Thanks poushy , this is a major advancment, the only thing missing is that the final result should be with the original text, like this: <div id="output">everyone <span>David</span> wants to travel the world  <span>Paris</span> with a car  <span>Fia</span></div>

Comment: In that case you can use replace instead of match.  I have modified the answer to reflect the same.